# What statistical test would be appropriate to analyse these proportions?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have this matrix:

```
habitats <- matrix(c(0.4,0.1,0.5, 0.2,0.6, 0.2), nrow = 3, ncol = 2,
               dimnames = list(c("grassland","intertidal","saltmarsh"),
                               c("site1","site2")))

habitats

           site1 site2
grassland    0.4   0.2
intertidal   0.1   0.6
saltmarsh    0.5   0.2
```

I want to know if the habitat in site1 differs from the habitat in site2. Each site is split into three habitat types and the matrix shows the proportion of each habitat in each of site1 and site2.

Initially, I thought a chi-squared would be appropriate but I have been made aware chi-squared should only be used if data are frequencies.

What test could I use to tell if the habitat differs between site1 and site2?

Comment: how is the proportion calculated? the habitats do differ: this is a descriptive statement that does not need to be tested with infernetial statistics unless there is sampling involved in these measurements...

Comment: Could you clarify - how were the numbers in the table obtained?

Comment: no sampling involved. Numbers obtained by measuring what proportion of each site is covered by each habitat.

Comment: Your sample consists of two sites with measurements on three linearly dependent measurements. Assumong there are not gross measurement errors present, the two sites differ. There is no need to do a test here.