# What would be the most appropriate analysis to compare repeated measures, multiple proportions of 100% across time?

Tags: categorical-data, repeated-measures, chi-squared-test

Let's say you have a person who wishes to increase their running endurance. They complete three runs, where the proportion of time (as a %) they are running, walking, and resting are logged. Is there an appropriate statistical test that would tell you if these proportions are significantly different?

[image]

There was another post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77026/what-statistical-test-would-be-appropriate-to-analyse-these-proportions), but their comparisons were unrelated, whereas the comparisons here are for the same person, across multiple time-points.